# Apache fresh installation on centos 6.4 says You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, centos, httpd.conf

In a fresh centos 6.4 server i installed httpd using yum but when tried to access server with public ip it says "You don't have permission to access / on this server"

my document root is /var/www/html

it has full right to be accessed by apache:
[root@3 html]# ll /var/www/html/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache   28  6æ 18 15:40 2013 1.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache    0  6æ 18 12:11 2013 i.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache    0  6æ 18 12:11 2013 i.php

but still when i access any of the file it says "You don't have permission to access"

my apache error log says:
[Tue Jun 18 15:42:13 2013] [error] [client 2XX.XX.XX.XXX] attempt to invoke directory as script: /var/www/html/
[Tue Jun 18 15:42:13 2013] [error] [client 2XX.XX.XX.XXX] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /var/www/error/noindex.html

for this i already tries "+ExecCGI" option in httpd.conf but there is no luck!

Please help!!

Comment: try [disabling the firewall](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-linux-firewall-under-centos-rhel-fedora/) or maybe it's an issue with bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by adding permission on the dir